# Django 1.9.1 NoReverseMatch when using django.auth

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn django by following the book "Django by Example" and probably due to conflicting versions i'm running into this problem when trying to use django.auth together with some URL settings in 
settings.py.
Im getting totally frustrated by now since i have no idea how to even begin debugging this error. Any help or advice would be much appreciated
Here's the relevant part of the settings.py file

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')
```

app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout-then-login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout_then_login'),
}
```

Main urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),

]
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvB5F.png)

updated settings.py :

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account:login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:logout')
```

Comment: Have you included your `account` urls in the main urls.py file?

Comment: Also all the templates are in the correct directories

Comment: Have you put `account` app in your INSTALLED_APPS - **at the top of other apps**?

Comment: also yes. Tried every trick i could find on this site. have my app on top, next one django.contrib.auth..

Comment: Have you run `migrate`?

Comment: Also yes. Just ran the command again - no changes detected

Comment: This whole problem started when I wanted to use djangos built in views, when i was using my own view for authentification everything was ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `app_name` that sets up a *namespace* that will be used when you `include()` that urls.py somewhere else.

So there's no url with the name `"login"`, instead it's called `"account:login"`, and that's the name you have to pass to reverse().

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account:login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:logout')
```

Relevant docs: [URL namespaces and included URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

If you are using [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) (you should), you can use the management command `show_urls` to get a nicely formatted list of all the url routes that are registered in your project.

Comment: I would be happy not to use app_name, but when i remove app_name , i don't know why, but then the url to the admin.site breaks down ?!

Comment: you can just change the `reverse_lazy()` calls. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now I get a TypeError at /account/ , argument to reversed() must be a sequence. and when i try to access /account/login/ i get the same NoReverseMatch error

Comment: Once the first bug was fixed, a different bug was revealed. That's pretty common. `urlpatterns` should be a list. Change the `{}` surrounding your urlpatterns in `account/urls.py` into `[]`.

Comment: Ok. I still got the NoReverseMatch at /account but at least it redirected to the correct url: /account/login/?next=/account/ .

Comment: Then you are using invalid url names elsewhere as well. The traceback should tell you where you have to fix it. It's either when you call `reverse`, `reverse_lazy` or use the template tag `{% url `

Comment: I found the problem sort of... I removed the {% extends "base.html" %} tag from the login  template in registration/login.html and it works!!

Comment: You can also fix "base.html". It probably contains something like this `{% url 'login' %}`.